# How to build an ASP.Net site that contains several silverlight projects with msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, msbuild

I have a VS2008 solution that contains and ASP.Net website, an ASP.Net WCF service, and several silverlight projects/applications.  Building the solution under any of the Configurations that I have defined (Debug, Staging, Release) in the IDE works great.  I also have an MSbuild project that builds the solution using an MSBuild Task, runs all the unit tests, and then deploys the site and the service etc. via FTP.

If I do a clean build in the msbuild project, it fails as it seems to fail to copy over the built silverlight libraries into the dependent projects and I get lots of missing reference errors.  If I just open up the solution in the IDE, switch to the same Configuration and build, it works fine and then the msbuild project works fine.

What special steps do I need to take to build a solution that contains silverlight projects?  Do I need to specifically build all the projects and copy over the dll outputs??

I am new to msbuild.  Thanks in advance.  Here is how I am building the sln file in the msbuild project:

```
<MSBuild Projects="mainsite.sln" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build each project to a different directory, and then rely on copying the dependant assemblies locallly, I would change all of the projects to output to the same directory and then turn off the CopyLocal option on the references between the projects.